# Find a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

If we pick some element $x$ in the $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, how do we write out the homomorphism explicitly?

Comment: "The" homomorphism? You mean the $n\mapsto x^n$ one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element in $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ can be identified with $e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$. So it suffice to find the image of $1$. Suppose $f(1)=e^{i\theta}$, then $f(n)=e^{in\theta}$. I will leave you to check this is indeed a homomorphism.